# GraphView always start on zero, and dynamically data

Tags: android, arrays, android-graphview

How can I make my GraphView always start on zero and not on the lowest number of my data ? For example if my data received is `{10,44,1,15}`, the bottom one will be the `1` and I wanted to be zero. How can I do that ?

And how can I make the `GraphViewSeries` dynamically ? For example I receive an array with data and I want depending the size of the array to make the `GraphViewSeries`, like if I receive an array with 3 elements the `GraphViewSeries` will be like this:

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(
                new GraphViewData[] { 
                        new GraphViewData(1, total[0]),
                        new GraphViewData(2, total[1]),
                        new GraphViewData(3, total[2])});
```

If the array has 5 elements with would be like this:

```
GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(
                new GraphViewData[] { 
                        new GraphViewData(1, total[0]),
                        new GraphViewData(2, total[1]),
                        new GraphViewData(3, total[2]),
                        new GraphViewData(4, total[3]),
                        new GraphViewData(5, total[4]) });
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the min and max values like this:

```
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(context, "Graph name")
graphView.setManualYAxisBounds((double) max, (double) min);
```

For dynamic series you can do this:

```
GraphViewData[] data = new GraphViewData[total.length];
for (int a = 0; a < total.length; a++) {
    data[a] = new GraphView.GraphViewData(a, total[a]);
}
```

then you add your data to a series like this:

```
GraphViewSeriesStyle style = new GraphViewSeriesStyle(Color.rgb(150, 150, 150), 2);
GraphViewSeries series = new GraphViewSeries(driverName.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase(), style, data);
```

for the official documentation refer to [here](http://android-graphview.org/).

Comment: I forgot to change driverName to a general string, it should be the string to show in the legend.

Comment: I don't know why but my array is {3,1,2,2}, but when I create the graph I get 1,3,2,2 :/

Comment: And how can I align the bars to the horizontal labels ?

Comment: I'm not sure about taht, i started using this library this afternoon :)

Comment: I had changed the order `graphView.setManualYAxisBounds((double) max, (double) min);` I was putting `min, max`

Answer (score 5):

In GraphView 4.x, setting the axis min and max values has to be done via the viewport:

```
graphView.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
graphView.getViewport().setMinY(min);
graphView.getViewport().setMaxY(max);
```

'graphView.setManualYAxisBounds()' no longer exists.

See also http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/migration-from-31-to-40